# How to generete charts according to the user selection using Modern UI (Metro) Charts?

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, charts

I'm using Modern UI (Metro) Charts in my projects. You can find the library here http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/

I have a combobox in my GUI and it contains types of charts. What I need to do is when user selects a chart type, I want to generate that chart. I can do it manually by just editing the xaml code which generates graph. But how can I do it according to user selection? Need help as soon as possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working exemple :

MainWindow XAML :

```
<Window>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding ChartTypes, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SimpleStringProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Select Option"></ComboBox>
        <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="FrameTest" Source="{Binding SelectedPageChart, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </Frame>            
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> ChartTypes { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ChartTypes = new ObservableCollection<string>();      
            ChartTypes.Add("Pie");
            ChartTypes.Add("Doughnut");

        }

        private string _simpleStringProperty;
        public string SimpleStringProperty
        {
            get { return _simpleStringProperty; }
            set
            {
                _simpleStringProperty = value;
                if (value.Equals("Pie"))
                {
                    SelectedPageChart = new Uri("PageTest.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                }
                if (value.Equals("Doughnut"))
                {
                    SelectedPageChart = new Uri("PageTest2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                }
                OnPropertyChanged("SimpleStringProperty");

            }
        }

        private Uri _selectedPageChart;   
        public Uri SelectedPageChart
        {
            get { return _selectedPageChart; }
            set
            {
                _selectedPageChart = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPageChart");
            }
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

PageTest XAML :

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.PageTest"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:metroChart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart" mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="PageTest">
<Grid>

    <metroChart:PieChart
    Style="{StaticResource MinimalChartStyle}"
    ChartTitle="Minimal Pie Chart"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <metroChart:PieChart.Series>
            <metroChart:ChartSeries
            SeriesTitle="Errors"
            DisplayMember="Category"
            ValueMember="Number"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}" />
        </metroChart:PieChart.Series>
    </metroChart:PieChart>

</Grid>
```

PageTest2 XAML:

```
  <Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.PageTest2"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:metroChart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="PageTest2">

    <Grid>
        <metroChart:DoughnutChart
        Style="{StaticResource MinimalChartStyle}"
        ChartTitle="Minimal Pie Chart"
        ChartSubTitle="Chart with fixed width and height"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >
            <metroChart:PieChart.Series>
                <metroChart:ChartSeries
                SeriesTitle="Errors"
                DisplayMember="Category"
                ValueMember="Number"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}" />
            </metroChart:PieChart.Series>
        </metroChart:DoughnutChart>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Pages have same viewmodel in order to display same chart:

```
 public class ChartViewModel
        {
                public ObservableCollection<TestClass> Errors { get; private set; }
                public ChartViewModel()
            {
                Errors = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
                Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Globalization", Number= 75 });
                Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Features", Number = 2 });
                Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "ContentTypes", Number = 12 });
                Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Correctness", Number = 83 });
                Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Best Practices", Number = 29 });
            }

            private object selectedItem = null;
            public object SelectedItem
            {
                get
                {
                    return selectedItem;
                }
                set
                {
                    selectedItem = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

What I've done here is to use a frame to load dinamically pages containing desired charts. Hope it helps!

Comment: Where do I need to use the ChartViewModel class? And you have to add the code for TestClass in it. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, its a viewmodel with data from TestClass, in code-behind of the pages you should set the data context : Datacontext = new ChartViewModel();

Comment: Thanks. Worked it out

Comment: I need you help again on this. Here in mainWindow ViewModel you have get the selected pages and redirecting them using a uri. When generating charts I need to pass some parameters to charts through that uri. as an example

SelectedPageChart = new Uri("PageTest2.xaml?param1=2", UriKind.Relative);

And I want to use that parameter in PageTest2.xaml.cs

what is the way of doing that? Is that possible?

Comment: please write another question because the answer is not so simple I think

Comment: I have posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426638/how-generate-graphs-using-modern-ui-charts-according-to-user-inputs

have a look into it